# Sharing python globals() cross files

Tags: python, global-scope

This questions is related global-scope of python.

There are have two files below.

**fileA.py**

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(globals())
```

**fileB.py**

```
import fileA

def global_funcB():
    return "global_funcB"
```

When I run `python fileB.py`. The globals() of fileA.py only contains fileA's content.

Is that possible to get address of `global_funcB` in fileB.py from fileA.py? So far, I only can do this from fileB.py.

> Note: for my purpose, there is no way to import fileB from fileA.py

---

**[Edit]**

Let me describe my purpose clearly.

**loader.py**

```
class loader(object):
    def __init__(self, module):
        print(dir(module))
```

**builder.py + class function**

```
import loader

class someobj(object):
   def somefunc(self):
       pass

loader.loader(someobj)
```

If I passing some module/class from fileB to build fileA, then it's possible to fetch function of fileB.

However, if the function in builder.py is globally.

**builder.py + global function**

```
import loader

def someglobalfunc(self):
   pass

loader.loader(???)
```

I have no idea how to pass globals() as a module/class to another file.

Comment: Actually, `import`s are exactly for that thing you need. Could you give us more broad context of your problem and explain, why can't you use it?

Comment: I dont think its possible without importing fileB from fileA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the globals of file `B` inside file `A` after importing it in `B` and use the globals in `B` it's completely redundant, as you can simple get the globals within `B` and use them.

If you want to get those globals and use them with `A` it's not possible because at the time you are running the file `A` there is not `B` in it's name space which is completely obvious.

Based on your edit:

If you are going to pass multiple global function to `loader` you can find all functions within your global namespace and pass them to `loader`. For example  you can look for objects that have a `__call__` attribute (if your classes and other objects are not callable). Or as a more general way use `types.FunctionType`.

```
from typing import FunctionType
functions = [obj for obj in globals().values() if isinstance(obj, FunctionType)]
```

The loader class:

```
class loader:
    def __init__(self, *modules):
        for module in modules:
            print(dir(module))
```

Your executable file:

```
import loader
from typing import FunctionType

def someglobalfunc1(self):
   pass
def someglobalfunc2(self):
   pass

functions = [obj for obj in globals().values() if isinstance(obj, FunctionType)]
loader.loader(*functions)
```

Comment: @KirChou I don't see any differences between two cases, you can still pass your function object to `loader`. Note that almost every thing in python is an object.

Comment: Yep, I know I can pass function to loader.py, but consider there are multiple global functions. How to pass them **in one object**? What I knew is globals(), but I found that I can not share globals as a module.

Comment: Thanks. tbh, the solution is not over my expectation, but it seems like no other way to achieve this.